Synchronize the Synology Calendar app between two Synology NAS
I have two Synology NAS with btrfs and snapshot replication. The syncronization of data between NAS works well. But the syncronization of the applications Calendar & Contacts cannot be setup within the DSM.
How can I synchronize the apps every night automatically?
Has someone solved this issue using a bash script with some Synology shell commands and rsync?
I have asked the official Synology support. They confirmed that there is no chance to use DSM directly. I should use third party apps. But they don't provide a list of possible third party solutions. I have suggested to add an enhancement request but nothing happened.
